# Word to refer to someone who takes an oath

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I need to find the word for someone who swears an oath in writing a description of a ceremony. E.g.,'At this point in the ceremony, the **[insert-word-for-oathtaker]** raises her right hand.'

Etymologically, the word that seems most correct is *juror*, but that seems wrong given how specifically its modern use refers to a member of a jury. Is there a word that fits this situation? *Jurat* and *adjuror* both seem to have their own specific meanings today which do not mean simply one taking an oath.

Comment: Why do you think oathtaker or oath-taker not adequate?

Definition of 'oath' at [Law.com Legal Dictionary](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1361) n. 1) a swearing to tell the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth, which would subject the **oath-taker** to a prosecution for the crime of perjury if he/she knowingly lies in a statement either orally in a trial or deposition or in writing.

Comment: Perhaps you could emphasize the role of the oath-taker, rather than the oath itself. Example: The *inductee* / *juror* / *officer* / *new citizen* will raise her right hand.

Comment: "swearer" is in Lexico and M-W, although as is common with agent nouns in dictionaries, neither gives a specific definition (Lexico has an example where it means someone who blasphemes). But it seems reasonable to use it and assume the reader can work out you mean someone swearing an oath, not effing and blinding.

Answer (score 2):

One relevant standard legal term is **deponent**. From Henry Black, *A Dictionary of Law* (1910):

> **DEPONENT.** In practice. One who *deposes* (that is, testifies or makes oath in *writing*) to the truth of certain facts ; one who gives under oath testimony which is reduced to writing ; one who makes oath to a written statement. The party making an affidavit is generally so called.

Another legal term very similar in meaning to *deponent* is **affiant**, which Black defines as follows:

> **AFFIANT.** The person who makes and subscribes to an affidavit. The word is used, in this sense, interchangeably with "deponent." But the latter term should be reserved as the designation of one who makes a deposition.

Yet another potentially relevant term in Black's dictionary is **jurator**:

> **JURATOR.** A juror; a compurgator ["One of several neighbors of a person accused of a crime, or charged as a defendant in a civil action, who appeared and swore that they believed him on his oath"].

Note that Black's entry for *juror* does not limit its meaning to "member of a jury":

> **JUROR.** One member of a jury. Sometimes, one who takes an oath ; as in the term "non-juror," a person who refuses certain oaths.

Of these four terms, *jurator* is the one least encumbered with other common meanings that refer to specific legal roles, but it is a rather unfamiliar (and certainly rarely used) word.